# Render content depending on listbox selected option - headless ui - vuejs

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, headless-ui

We have this Listbox from HeadlessUI.
**Issue:** unable to render content depending on listbox selected option.

This is the listbox:

```
<Listbox v-model="selectedElement">
        <ListboxButton class="">
             <span class="block truncate">{{ selectedElement.name }}</span>
         </ListboxButton>
         <ListboxOptions>
            <ListboxOption
                 v-slot="{ active, selected }"
                 v-for="element in elements"
                 :key="element.id"
                 :value="element"
                 as="template">
                 <li>
                    <span{{ element.name }}</span>
                 </li>
              </ListboxOption>
        </ListboxOptions>
 </Listbox>
```

The following isn't working:

```
 <div v-if="id === 0">
     render content related to id=0
 </div
```

data

```
const elements = [
  { id: 0, name: 'Simple elements' },
  { id: 1, name: 'Call to action' },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Condition was wrong...

```
<div v-if="selectedElement.id === 0">
    render content related to id=0
</div
```

...works